# Copy state of another branch and commit them in git

Tags: git, branch

I have two branches in Git, A and B. I want to be in branch B and ”checkout” the complete ”state” (not history) of A but still  be in B, and then commit that as one single change of B.

So files that are present in B but not A are deleted in that commit, files are present in A but not B are created in the commit, and files that differ between A and B are modified in B. So the history of B is kept but the ”states” of A and B are identical.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old way of doing that would be (assuming you are on B already):

```
git checkout A -- .
git commit -m "single change to get to A's content"
```

The new way is:

```
git restore --worktree --staged --source=A -- .
git commit -m "single commit to get to A's content"
```

The longer but possible way would be:

```
git checkout --detach A
git reset --soft B # set the branch pointer (well, HEAD, actually) to where B points to
git commit -m "single commit to get to A's content"
# now you have this single revision after B that has the same content of A
# set B over here and checkout
git branch -f B
git checkout B
```

That would also work.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any practical difference between the old way and the new? And how come I don’t switch over to A when I write ”git checkout A .”? Is it the ending period?

Comment: the new way is using a _newish_ command (restore) which was built to be able to handle things _without_ using checkout.... because (answering your second question at the same time) checkout has _many_ different usages which can make UX a little confusing (as your second question implies). So, if you run `git checkout something -- whatever`, you get `whatever` content from `something` **BUT** you **do not** _switch_ to `something` (and I guess that also explains why we now have `git switch` as well, right?).

Comment: The old way did not work - files that were present in B but not A were not deleted so A and B were not identical. The new way worked fine. I haven't tried the longer way. Thanks!

Comment: @DrLjotsson: yes, the "old way" requires an initial `git rm -r .` before the `git checkout A .` to clear things out. There's yet another way (because this is Git) but the `git restore` method is the one to use at this point.